MySQL 8 Trigger - Unknown Table 'NEW' in field list
I am setting up a database and trying my hand at implementing triggers. All Tables and the trigger upload into the database without warning, however when I activate the trigger on update of the table operator I get an error message
UPDATE operator SET `NAME_FIRST`='JOHN' WHERE `OPERATOR_ID`=0;
SQL Error (1109): Unknown table 'NEW' in field list
I suspect that it is in the Auditor Triggers.
Database export with HEIDISQL
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             12.8.0.6908
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

-- Dumping structure for table test.auditor
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auditor` (
  `OPERATOR_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `IS_ACTIVE` enum('TRUE','FALSE') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`OPERATOR_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `auditor_FK_OPERATOR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`OPERATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `operator` (`OPERATOR_ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table test.auditor: ~0 rows (approximately)

-- Dumping structure for procedure test.auditor_validation
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `auditor_validation`(
    IN `OPERATOR_ID` INT
)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE myVar VARCHAR(5);
    SELECT
        `IS_ACTIVE` INTO myVar
    FROM
        operator
    WHERE
        operator.OPERATOR_ID = OPERATOR_ID;
    IF NEW.ACTIVE = 'TRUE' AND myVar = 'FALSE' THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Operator is marked as inactive'; 
    END IF; 
END//
DELIMITER ;

-- Dumping structure for table test.operator
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `operator` (
  `OPERATOR_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME_FIRST` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME_LAST` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BUSINESS_ID` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IS_ACTIVE` enum('TRUE','FALSE') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`OPERATOR_ID`),
  KEY `BUSINESS_ID` (`BUSINESS_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table test.operator: ~2 rows (approximately)
INSERT INTO `operator` (`OPERATOR_ID`, `NAME_FIRST`, `NAME_LAST`, `BUSINESS_ID`, `IS_ACTIVE`) VALUES
    (-1, 'JANE', 'DOE', '456XYZ', 'TRUE'),
    (2, 'JOE', 'DOE', 'ABC123', 'FALSE');

-- Dumping structure for trigger test.auditor_before_insert
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `auditor_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `auditor` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    CALL auditor_validation(NEW.OPERATOR_ID);

END//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLDTMP_SQL_MODE;

-- Dumping structure for trigger test.auditor_before_update
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `auditor_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `auditor` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    CALL auditor_validation(NEW.OPERATOR_ID);

END//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLDTMP_SQL_MODE;

-- Dumping structure for trigger test.operator_after_update
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `operator_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `operator` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE OP_ID INT;
SET OP_ID = NEW.OPERATOR_ID;

IF NEW.IS_ACTIVE = 'FALSE' THEN
UPDATE auditor
SET auditor.IS_ACTIVE = 'FALSE'
WHERE auditor.OPERATOR_ID = OP_ID;
END IF;

END//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLDTMP_SQL_MODE;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=IFNULL(@OLD_TIME_ZONE, 'system') */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IFNULL(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 1) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_NOTES, 1) */;

I have tried replacing the NOW.%Value% in the Triggers but that would sometimes stop the error from showing up but not always
EDIT: the error shows up with insert into auditor (`Operator_ID`,`IS_ACTIVE`) VALUES (2, 'FALSE'); as well.
apparently the error only shows when the auditor table gets changed or a parent of an auditor record gets changed, definitely points to the procedure

i can not see any problem https://dbfiddle.uk/4SGBAlSJ

Don't name your procedure variable operator_id the same as a column name. You might get away with it this time because one is qualified and the other is not, but in general, you should make sure the procedure variable is distinct.

Another thing to try is insert into the Auditor table insert into auditor (`Operator_ID`,`IS_ACTIVE`) VALUES (2, 'FALSE'); It gets me the same error on a fresh database with the code I had posted (as a query)

The posted code won't fail because the triggers are never invoked and nor is the procedure (which probably will fail because NEW is out of scope) please review and fix so that we can reproduce your issue.

I found the NEW reference that was causing the issue, as part of the auditor_validation procedure, changing that into a parameter fixed the issue and allows insertions to the auditor table and updates to the operator table
